# Roboto Condensed Font not rendering properly in mozilla firefox

Tags: css, firefox, webfonts

I am using RobotoCondensed downloaded from google Web Fonts. I am using the font from my server. I have created the css like below.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
    src: url('../fonts/RobotoCondensed-Light.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/RobotoCondensed-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('../fonts/RobotoCondensed-Light.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('../fonts/RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf')  format('truetype'), 
         url('../fonts/RobotoCondensed-Light.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); 
    }
```

> All the font types specified are present in the folder that I have specified in the url.

I am using the font family like this

```
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
```

The things are going smooth with respect to IE9 and Chrome. But when it comes to Mozilla Firefox it is not so.

[image: Except mozilla firefox]

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Consider posting the URL. This would let us see the actual requests for font files and server responses to them.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela : I have not created any URL for the website. The website is just for a local network.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. The site is working properly when I hosted in IIS.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088263/web-fonts-dont-work-in-firefox-on-local-but-do-on-server?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the one off the Google Fonts Api and it works in Firefox:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto Condensed Regular'), local('RobotoCondensed-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/robotocondensed/v7/Zd2E9abXLFGSr9G3YK2MsNxB8OB85xaNTJvVSB9YUjQ.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Maybe try specifying style and weight.

Comment: Maybe give this link a look through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I got the solution. Presently it is working fine when hosted in server. Actually it was a problem.

Comment: I had the same issue but serving from S3 and had to set my headers on the fonts with Access-Control-Allow-Origin = mydomain. If you're serving form your server, then there's a bunch of server snippets like the link posted above.

Answer (score 0):

just remove : font-weight: 300;  from woff